# SQL Stored Procedure with Loop and Update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

How to Do the Loop in the following Ledger Table to update the balance using Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE Ledger
(
PersonID int,
dr float,
cr float,
bal float
); 

INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, dr, cr, bal)
VALUES 
('1001',105,0,0),
('1001',0,5.25,0),
('1002',0,150,0),
('1001',0,15,0),
('1002',73,0,0); 

SELECT PersonID, dr, cr, bal FROM Ledger;
```

How to Loop and Update the balance

```
bal += (dr - cr);
```

and Finally list out the PersonID with Last balance. How to Loop and Update the Ledger using MySQL ?

The Expecting Output Update Query is

```
PersonID       Dr      Cr          Bal
1001           105     0           105
1001           0       5.25        99.75
1001           0       15          84.75


PersonID       Dr      Cr          Bal
1002           0       150         -150
1002           73      0            -77
```

The Expected Output SELECT Query is

```
    PersonID       Dr      Cr          Bal
    1001           0       15          84.75
    1002           73      0           -77
```

Comment: SELECT PersonID, dr, cr, sum(bal) FROM Ledger GROUP by PersonID;

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below. Should solve your problem.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addbal`()
BEGIN
declare no_record int default 0;
declare pi int;
declare newbal float default 0;
declare mydr,mycr,mybal float default 0;
declare cicle int default 0;
declare cur_ledger CURSOR FOR 
select personid,dr,cr,bal FROM Ledger order by personid;
declare continue handler for not found


set no_record = 1;
open cur_ledger;
set @prevbal = 0;

chg_bal: LOOP
 FETCH cur_ledger INTO pi,mydr,mycr,mybal;
 IF no_record = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE chg_bal;
 END IF;

IF @previd != pi then
set @prevbal = 0;
end if;
set @newbal = (mydr-mycr) + @prevbal;

update Ledger set bal = @newbal  where cr = mycr and dr = mydr and personid = pi ; 

set @prevbal = @newbal;
set @previd = pi;

END LOOP chg_bal;

close  cur_ledger;


END
```